# creating autorun.inf for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc, autorun

I'm trying to create a dvd for an offline version of a site (for language learners) and would like it to autorun. However, it appears not to work on Windows 7. The autorun.inf file is only:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=index.html
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: Added autorun tag & put the code into a code block for clarity, please check that it is correct.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/735539/709458) and use the autorun pro to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be correct.

You could also use something like:

```
[autorun]
open=command /c start /max index.htm
```

You might want to try that just to see if it works.

However, I suspect the simplest answer would be that you have autoplay disabled - perhaps though some previous tweaking of Windows? Or via a Group Policy if it is a PC on a Windows Domain. If you insert a blank CD-R or DVD-R, do you get the pop-up dialog? If not, then autoplay is disabled. You need autoplay enabled in order to run autorun.inf

If autoply is disabled and if you are confident editing the registry and you are not on a PC belonging to your enterprise (unless you have authority), you could try editing the registry. I believe the correct entry is found at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CDRom
```

There should be an entry called "AutoRun" and it should be set to 1 not 0.

To check the group policies, run *gpedit.msc* and go to the section "Windows Components \ AutoPlay Policies". The set "Turn off Autoplay" to **disable**.

Microsoft provide some pointers to autoplay security issues [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2009/04/28/autorun-changes-in-windows-7.aspx).